# Backbone js.How to pass data from view to template in backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone js. Can some one help me to send data in template from my view.

My View has this code:

```
$('#top-bar').html(_.template($("#loginned-top-bar-template").html()));
```

and my template contains

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="topbar-username"><%user_name%></a></li>
```

and I want to send "awsome_user"to it.

It would be great if any one would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var compiled = _.template($("#loginned-top-bar-template").html());
var templateVars = {user_name : 'awesome_user' };
$('#top-bar').html( compiled(templateVars) );
```

`<%user_name%>` should be `<%=user_name%>` if you want to print the variable.

If you want to use other `user_name`, set `user_name` property before compiled function called.

```
var compiled = _.template($("#loginned-top-bar-template").html());
var templateVars = {user_name : 'awesome_user' };
templateVars.user_name = Parse.User.current().get("name");
$('#top-bar').html( compiled(templateVars) );
```

Comment: what if I want to replace "awesome_user" with my Parse object's property. which would be-- Parse.User.current().get("name") --